# Should I create a directive for each type of user input

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creating a greenfield application in Angular.
I was wondering what to do with the userinput.
I will create 10+ date inputs, 20 text inputs, 8 dropdowns, 30 buttons, 10+ currency input etc., all with validation.

With my background as a .NET developer I am used to have a lot of html for each control (html control, lots of bootstrap, validation line), duplicated throughout all the html.

Now in Angular there are directives.

**Should I create a directive for each type of user input?**

And with 'should I' I mean in a pragmatic way (because it's very handy) and/or a architectual way (because it is better architectual).

The second reason I ask is because I find the directives syntax one of the more difficult parts to learn.

Comment: You should look into the new component syntax if you're struggling with directives - it's a lot easier to learn, and will come in handy if you ever want to migrate to Angular 2. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component

Comment: Looks good. But I'm using Angular 1.4.7, and this is only in 1.5, or am I wrong?

Comment: It's only in Angular 1.5, you're correct. 1.4.7 to 1.5 is a easy migration though, there's very few breaking changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should not create any directive for inputs / selects.
Html code for inputs and selects is to short and easy, so directive will not help you at all. Instead of use on inputs build in angular directives Lets look:

```
<input ng-model="" 
  ng-disable="" 
  ng-pattern="for email format"
```

for select you can use also ng-options
for validation purpose you ca use something like that:

```
ng-class="{'has-error': !joinForm.password.$valid && !joinForm.password.$pristine }"
```

So I think custom directives will only complicate your work

Comment: I choose this way to go, and I have not yet foundI needed the directives.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of things in angular for inputs and so on.

You may have to add directives for custom validation, you can find sample on the net.

Check this sample http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-a-custom-angularjs-unique-value-directive

Note that this sample is not the cleanest one.

This one is better : http://www.codelord.net/2014/11/02/angularjs-1-dot-3-taste-async-validators/

However i think you should start with implementing the 1st one before going for the 2nd if you want, to do it in a step by step way. And yes directives syntax and usage of ngModelController are not so easy.

Other sample : in order to reduce the html to type and ensure that i have all my fields with the same presentation (label on the left, error messages, info tooltip on the right,...). I create a directive for this. It's a matter of how far do you want to go, and how long do you have, to do this.

Most of all : before reinventing the wheel, check on the net, if it isn't supported natively by angular, there is a tons of things already done and shared online.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to agree with Przemek that in general it would over complicate things. With the exception that you might build a re-useable form that you want to pre-build for use in multiple places. I have worked on an Angular app recently which had multiple edit panels and we essentially built custom directives for common components that were then put together to make individual forms/edit panels. But not single elements.